# Django / Closure: How to validate AJAX form via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, django, forms, closures

I'm using Django and Google's Closure javascript library, and I want to do some form processing via AJAX.

Currently, I have a button on the page that says "Add score."  When you click it, it fires off a goog.net.Xhrio request to load another URL with a form on it and display the contents in a little pop up box, via a call to `loadForm()`.

```
loadForm = function(formId) {
  var form = goog.dom.getElement(formId);
  goog.style.setElementShown(goog.dom.getElement('popup-box'), true);
  goog.net.XhrIo.send(form.action, displayForm, form.method);
}

displayForm = function(e) {
  goog.dom.getElement('popup-box').innerHTML = e.target.getResponseText();
}
```

The Django form that gets loaded is a very basic model form, with a simple "score" attribute that gets validated against a number range.  Here's the code I have to process the form submission:

```
def Score(request):
  obj = ScoreModel.get(pk=request.POST['obj_id'])
  form = ScoreForm(request.POST, instance=obj)

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Score saved!')
    return shortcuts.redirect('index')
  else:
    context_vars = {'score': score, 'form': quarter_form}
    shortcuts.render_to_response(
        'score_form.html', context_vars,
        context_instance=context.RequestContext(request))
```

This would all work fine if the form to enter the score itself was just displayed on the page, but because it is an AJAX popup, it doesn't work properly.  If I just do a simple form submission (via HTML submit button), it works fine if the data is valid.  But if the data isn't valid, instead of displaying the form with errors in the popup, it just loads only the text that would've been displayed in the popup - the form with errors - in the main browser window rather than in the popup.

Conversely, if I submit the form via my `loadForm()` JS method above, it works perfectly fine if the form is invalid (and displays the invalid form in the popup box), but doesn't work if the form is valid (because the main index page ends up getting displayed in my popup's innerHTML).

I can't seem to figure out how to get the code to work in both scenarios.  So, how can I have my cake and eat it to?  :)

This is kind of a strange issue, so if I didn't explain it well enough, let me know and I'll try to clarify.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to pop the form ?

Comment: That's just how the UI is set up.  All the forms pop out over the content, it's just for this form we actually need validation for the first time.

Comment: ok - when you do a post to the server django will run the validation and then display the form with errors (if validation failed), I'm not sure how you can do it into a popup since you need to render the form template again. A different way to do it to have a AjaxMixin - look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example.

Comment: Thanks @silviud.  I had read through those docs previous, unfortunately they do more or less the same thing (except more elegantly) to what I currently have - e.g. they can submit via AJAX, or via regular submission, but not one or the other at the same time depending upon form success.  Fortunately, I think I have an idea how to handle it, will follow up with an answer if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  The basic trick was, if the form submission was successful, instead of returning a redirect I returned a basic response object with a redirect status code and the URL to redirect to.  Then I modified my `displayForm()` to look for that and redirect if it was found.

Here's the modified code from the `Score()` function:

```
if form.is_valid():
  form.save()
  messages.success(request, 'Score saved!')
  redirect = shortcuts.redirect('index')
  return http.HttpResponse(content=redirect['Location'],
                           status=redirect.status_code)
```

And the modified `displayForm()`:

```
var displayForm = function(e) {
  var responseText = e.target.getResponseText();

  if (e.target.getStatus() == 302) {
    // If this was a redirect form submission, the response text will be the URL
    // to redirect to.
    window.location.href = responseText;
  } else {
    // Regular form submission.  Show the response text.
    goog.dom.getElement('popup-box').innerHTML = responseText;
  }
};
```