# how to update data using popup in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def setting(request):
    followup_form = FollowupSettingsForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        followup_form = FollowupSettingsForm(request.POST)
        if followup_form.is_valid():
            followup = followup_form.save(commit=False)
            """"""""""""
    return render(request, 'setting.html',{'form':followup_form})
```

models.py

```
class FollowupUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(' Followup name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField('Followup phone', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField('Followup email', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

setting.html

```
<div id="add_form" style="display:none">
    <form id="form"  method="post" action="." onsubmit="return form_validate()">{% csrf_token %}              
        <table  width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;">Name:</td><td>{{ form.name}}</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Phone No:</td><td>{{ form.phone_no}}
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td><td>{{ form.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">
        <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">Cancel</button>{% include "buttons/save.html" %}
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am uisng this popup to get the data from user and saving it.The above div inside the template is the popup code.The above views.py is to insert the data in database.

I am showing the saved data in UI as Name(as button),Email id.

I am passing the table id as id in Name button.On clicking the Name button,i want to fetch the data from db against that id in button and show in popup.If i click save button,changes gets updated in the database.I don't know how to update data using popup.Need help to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem? Why should updating in a popup be any different from updating from anywhere else?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Same thoughts here. I don't get what the problem here is, does he want to know how to use ajax for libraries like toastr or something?

Comment: @DanielRoseman since i am inserting the data via popup,i want to show the same data in popup for update.On clicking the Name button the data in that particular id should load in popup for update,if save is clicked it should update the table id.I know how to use ajax request,need a way to do this.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac since i am inserting the data via popup,i want to show the same data in popup for update.On clicking the Name button the data in that particular id should load in popup for update,if save is clicked it should update the table id.I know how to use ajax to get the id from html to views.py method,what i required is is it possible to use the same popup to insert and update the data against id.Need a way to do this please.

Comment: So, again, why is that different from loading a normal page with a form relating to a particular ID? Why is it special just because it's in a popup?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes,in setting.html,some other actions are also i am rendering ,this popup is the part of this page which insert or update a table in database.So i can't perform edit operation in page by passing the id in urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do i get any sample or answer for this.

Comment: Check out this similar question I asked a while back, which I figured out the answer to.  Not sure if it is the exact same situation, but might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437562/django-closure-how-to-validate-ajax-form-via-ajax

Comment: @Chad Thank you for your response,i solved it.

Comment: @user2439275 could you answer your own question and accept it then?

Answer (score -1):

Replace the column item `{{ form.name}}` by an input 
`<input id="name" value="{{ form.name }}">`. Do the same for `{{ form.phone_no }}` and `{{ form.email }}`.

Then you can take input from the user.